# Dynamic regex to capture

Tags: php, regex

Not sure if it is actually possible, but consider the following text:

```
INSERT INTO cms_download_history
SET
user_id     = '{$userId}',
download_id     = '{$fileId}',
remote_addr     = '{$remote_addr}',
doa = GetDate()";
```

I want to change that to be:

```
INSERT INTO cms_download_history
(user_id,download_id,remote_addr,doa)
VALUES('{$userId}','{$fileId}','{$remote_addr}',GetDate());
```

Doing a regex to find and replace this one is easy as I know how many columns I have but what if I am trying to do this for multiple similar queries without knowing the number of columns, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO mystery_table
SET
col1 = val1
col2 = val2
.... unknown number of columns and values.
```

Is there a dynamic regex that I can write that would detect that example?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you could simply split the string by (comma and) line break, as a first step.

Comment: @Xufox I'm not following...

Comment: You could split the text into individual lines and count, analyze and change them separately instead of applying a RegEx to the entire text. That would be easier, at least.

Comment: @Xufox You're absolutely right if i wasn't looking for a specific query, but in this case I need to know that they are preceded by `INSERT ... SET`

Comment: What language are you running this regex in?

Comment: @chris85 that's PHP and I'm using sublime to find and replace if it makes any difference.

Comment: I think you'll have to dive into the data to build this and I'm not sure Sublime could do that. I'd do this in PHP. I'd use `preg_replace_callback`, then `explode`, then `preg_match`.

Comment: @chris85 I suppose you're right, thanks.

Comment: PHP? Please tag correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if all queries look like this, with only a variable amount of columns, you can get the field names using a somewhat simple regex:

```
(\w+)\W*=\W*['"].+?(?!\\)['"],
```

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/tI5gR3/4). Here is what it does:

- It captures one or more word characters, if followed by:

  - Zero or more whitespace characters
  - An equal sign
  - Zero or more whitespace characters (again)
  - A `'` or `"` (start of a String)
  - One or more characters
  - An unescaped `'` or `"`
  - A comma

Note that this does assume that all values are strings. If you also need support for numbers, please let me know.

Comment: This is perfect actually thank you. and adjusting it to be `INSERT([^S]|S[^E]|SE[^T])*SET\n?((\w+)\W*=\W*['"].+?(?!\\)['"],\n)*` would help me catch only these lines that have "insert..set" before them